# What does the array keword in front of a method parameter mean in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, types, type-declaration

I stumbled upon a function declaration in PHP with the keyword `array` in front of a parameter. Now since you don't declare types in PHP, that looks really wired to me. Is that just an 'error', something someone put there that is not evaluated, or does it actually mean something?

```
public function sendSMTPMail(array $mailContent) { }
```

My feeling is that it shouldn't be there and it doesn't do anything, but maybe I'm wrong? Is there a difference to

```
public function sendSMTPMail($mailContent) { }
```

?

Comment: I believe it means you are required to use an array there. It should give a fatal error if you don't

Answer (score 1):

This is know as Type declarations it is also known as Type Hinting in PHP5.

Type declarations allow functions to specify parameters as certain types. If the given value is of the incorrect type, then an error is generated: in PHP 5, this will be a recoverable fatal error, while PHP 7 will throw a [TypeError](http://php.net/manual/en/class.typeerror.php) exception.

To specify a type declaration, the type name should be added before the parameter name. The declaration can be made to accept NULL values if the default value of the parameter is set to NULL.

**Valid types**

```
Type                    Description                                                Minimum PHP version
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Class/interface name    The parameter must be an instanceof the given class         PHP 5.0.0
                        or interface name.                 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                            
self                    The parameter must be an instanceof the same class as       PHP 5.0.0
                        the one the method is defined on. 
                        This can only be used on class and instance methods.    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
array                   The parameter must be an array.                             PHP 5.1.0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
callable                The parameter must be a valid callable.                     PHP 5.4.0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool                    The parameter must be a boolean value.                      PHP 7.0.0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
float                   The parameter must be a floating point number.              PHP 7.0.0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int                     The parameter must be an integer.                           PHP 7.0.0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
string                  The parameter must be a string.                             PHP 7.0.0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Original Source:** [PHP Function Argument Type Declaration](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration)

In your case have a look on following example:

```
function test(array $array)
{
    foreach($array as $k=>$v)
    {

    }
}

test(array("string")); //passed - no error
test("string"); //failed - catchable error
```

Output:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to test() must be of the type array, string given, called in /var/www/html/test/test1.php on line 12 and defined in /var/www/html/test/test1.php on line 3

Answer (score 0):

It is for **Type hinting**. If data passed to it is of other type then it will throw an error (**>= PHP 5**).

> Type declarations allow functions to specify parameters as certain types. If the given value is of the incorrect type, then an error is generated: in PHP 5, this will be a recoverable fatal error, while PHP 7 will throw a TypeError exception.

[Type Declaration](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration)

If the type is not defined the variable will be cast to the type of data passed. In this case if done have any validation for that data passed to it then it may cause problem during execution.